# Running a command with arguments in gulp

Tags: python, gulp, firefox-addon, child-process, gulp-shell

I'm rewriting some bash code in gulp that produces several add-ons/extensions for different browsers inspired by the [ublockorigin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) project on GitHub.

For Firefox there's a line that is supposed to run a python script which takes a destination directory as an argument. In gulp, I am having a hard time to run this python script.

I tried `gulp-run`, `gulp-shell`, `child_process`, but none of them are giving me the correct output.

When I run `python ./tools/make-firefox-meta.py ../firefox_debug/` from the command line I get my desired result and the `firefox_debug` directory is created.

Here is my code for `gulp-run`:

```
gulp.task("python-bsff", function(){
    return run("python ./tools/make-firefox-meta.py ../firefox_debug/").exec();
});
```

This is giving me this without actually doing anything:

```
$ gulp python-bsff
[14:15:53] Using gulpfile ~\dev\gulpfile.js
[14:15:53] Starting 'python-bsff'...
[14:15:54] Finished 'python-bsff' after 629 ms
$ python ./tools/make-firefox-meta.py ../firefox_debug/
```

Here is my code for `gulp-shell`:

```
gulp.task("python-bsff", function(){
   return shell.task(["./tools/make-firefox-meta.py ../firefox_debug/""]);
});
```

This is giving me this without actual result:

```
$ gulp python-bsff
[14:18:54] Using gulpfile ~\dev\gulpfile.js
[14:18:54] Starting 'python-bsff'...
[14:18:54] Finished 'python-bsff' after 168 μs
```

Here is my code for `child_process`: this was the most promising one, since I saw some output from python on the command line.

```
gulp.task("python-bsff", function(){
  var spawn = process.spawn;
  console.info('Starting python');
  var PIPE = {stdio: 'inherit'};
  spawn('python', ["./tools/make-firefox-meta.py `../firefox_debug/`"], PIPE);
});
```

It's giving me this output:

```
[14:08:59] Using gulpfile ~\dev\gulpfile.js
[14:08:59] Starting 'python-bsff'...
Starting python
[14:08:59] Finished 'python-bsff' after 172 ms
python: can't open file './tools/make-firefox-meta.py     ../firefox_debug/`': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can somebody tell me please, what change should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last one using `child_process.spawn()` is indeed the approach I would recommend, but the way you're passing the arguments to the `python` executable is wrong.

Each argument has to be passed as a separate element of the array. You can't just pass a single string. `spawn()` will interpret the string as a single argument and `python` will look for a file that is *literally* named `` ./tools/make-firefox-meta.py `../firefox_debug/` ``. Which, of course, doesn't exist.

So instead of this:

```
spawn('python', ["./tools/make-firefox-meta.py `../firefox_debug/`"], PIPE);
```

You need to do this:

```
spawn('python', ["./tools/make-firefox-meta.py", "../firefox_debug/"], PIPE);
```

You also need to properly signal [async completion](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support):

```
gulp.task("python-bsff", function(cb) {
  var spawn = process.spawn;
  console.info('Starting python');
  var PIPE = {stdio: 'inherit'};
  spawn('python', ["./tools/make-firefox-meta.py", "../firefox_debug/"], PIPE).on('close', cb);
});
```

Comment: sound better than before. the gulp is  Finished 'python-bsff' after 13 ms, but the changes that they python file is supposed to do is not there.
Anything directory addressing related can cause that?

Comment: It finishes after 13ms because you're not properly signalling async completion (see my edit). Also try running `python ./tools/make-firefox-meta.py ../firefox_debug/` on the command line (in the directory where your `gulpfile.js` is located). If it works there, it will work from gulp.

Comment: now, it is working. I learned signaling on asyc tasks from you. thanks